# Have to get Longest Run Coin Flip

Tags: java

Not sure exactly what to do,and whether it goes in my if statement or i make a new one.
Have to get the longest run for HEADS only.

```
public class LongestStreak extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public static final int FLIPS = 10;

    public void run()
    {
          int headFlips = 0;
          int tailFlips = 0;
          int longestRun = 0;
          int max = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < FLIPS; i++)
       { 
         if(Randomizer.nextBoolean())
         {
             System.out.println("Heads");
             headFlips++;
         }
         else
         {
         System.out.println("Tails");
         tailFlips++;
         }
      if ()
      {
          longestRun++;
          if(max < longestRun)
          {
              max = longestRun;
          }

      }
      else
      {
          longestRun = 0;
      }


       }//end for loop
       System.out.println("Longest streak of heads: " +longestRun);
    }
}
```

PLEASE HELP ME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Where is `Randomizer` defined?

Comment: Your "!" key is stuck...

Answer (score 1):

consider this simple logic

```
   longestRun = 0;
   currentRun = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < FLIPS; i++)
   { 
     if(Randomizer.nextBoolean())
     {
         System.out.println("Heads");
         // headFlips++;   - not used
         currentRun ++;
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Tails");
         // tailFlips++;  - not used
         longestRun = Math.max (longestRun, currentRun);
         currentRun = 0;
     }
  }

  // need to do after the loop too
  longestRun = Math.max (longestRun, currentRun);
  System.out.println("Longest streak of heads: " +longestRun);
```

Comment: Yours is a bit more elegant than mine ;) But not sure what `Randomizer` is or comes from though.

Comment: I would assume it is a Object of type https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: I'm guessing that it is someone who downvotes anyone who answers a "poor" question. I got the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
public class LongestStreak extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public static final int FLIPS = 10;

    public void run()
    {
          int longestRun = 0;
          int max = 0;

       Random r = new Random(); 
       for (int i = 0; i < FLIPS; i++)
       { 

         if(r.nextBoolean())
         {
             System.out.println("Heads");
             //increment max
             max++;
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Tails");
             //since the run is broken, compare the max & the longest run.
             //if max is greater, then set longest run to max
             if(max > longestRun)
              {
                  longestRun = max;
              }
              //reset your counter
              max = 0;
         }



       }//end for loop

       //need to compare last run of  flipping in case you end on heads
       if(max > longestRun)
       {
         longestRun = max;
       }
       System.out.println("Longest streak of heads: " +longestRun);
    }
}
```